# What is decltype and how is it used?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I haven't been able to find a good explanation of decltype. Please tell me, as a beginning programmer, what it does and why it is useful.

For example, I am reading a book that asked the following question:

> What would be the type of each variable and what value would each variable have when the code finishes?
>
> ```
> int a = 3, b = 4;    
> decltype(a) c = a;
> decltype((b)) d = a; 
> ++c; 
> ++d;
> ```

Can someone explain to me the answer and why, along with some good (beginner-level) examples?
A line-by-line explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Even [Wikipedia's explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference) seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`decltype` is a way to specify a type: You give it an *[expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.comma#nt:expression)*, and `decltype` gives you back a type which corresponds to the type of the expression, as explained in [[dcl.type.simple] p4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.simple#4):

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized *[id-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.general#nt:id-expression)* or an unparenthesized class member access ([[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ref)), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

Note that the first bullet covers `decltype(a)`, and the subsequent bullets cover double parentheses cases like `decltype((b))`.

Combining these rules with reference collapsing rules allows you to make sense of `decltype(e) &&`, which is always a "suitable" reference. (C++14 also adds `decltype(auto)` to give you the type-deduction of `auto` combined with the value category semantics of `decltype`.)

#### Examples

```
int foo();
int n = 10;

decltype(n) a = 20;             // a is an "int"    [unparenthesized id-expression]

decltype((n)) b = a;            // b is an "int &"  [(n) is an lvalue]
decltype((std::move(n))) c = a; // c is an "int &&" [(std::move(n)) is an xvalue]
decltype(foo()) d = foo();      // d is an "int"    [(foo()) is a prvalue]

decltype(foo()) && r1 = foo();  // int &&
decltype((n)) && r2 = n;        // int & [& && collapses to &]
```

It might be worth stressing the difference between `auto` and `decltype`: `auto` works on *types*, and `decltype` works on *expressions*.

You shouldn't be seeing or using `decltype` in "day-to-day" programming. It is most useful in generic (templated) library code, where the expression in question is not known and depends on a parameter. (By contrast, `auto` may be used generously all over the place.) In short, if you're new to programming, you probably won't need to use `decltype` for some time.

Comment: `decltype()` works on expressions. From the cppreference : _An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that specifies a computation._. Why does `decltype(x) var` works, with `int x ` previous declared?

Comment: @Kerrek SB `id-expression`? What's that?

Comment: Can i use `typeof` instead of `decltype`?

Comment: @SuB no, `typeof` is not a thing in C++. There is a C++26 proposal [P2858: `typeof` and `typeof_unqual` for C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2958r0.html) which may add this feature though.

Comment: This line decltype((std::move(n))) c = a; is wrong: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::remove_reference::type&&’ {aka ‘int&&’} to lvalue of type ‘int’. It should be something like `decltype((std::move(n))) c = std::move(some-variable);`