# why (var) is considered as lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to understand decltype in C++ through one of the stack overflow questions [What is decltype and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used)

Part of accepted answer is as below.

```
int foo();
int n = 10;

decltype(n) a = 20;             // a is an "int" [id-expression]

decltype((n)) b = a;            // b is an "int &" [(n) is an lvalue]

decltype(foo()) c = foo();      // c is an "int" [rvalue]

decltype(foo()) && r1 = foo();  // int &&
decltype((n)) && r2 = n;        // int & [& && collapses to &]
```

I couldn't understand below statement.

**decltype((n)) b = a;            // b is an "int &" [(n) is an lvalue]**

can any one please let me know why (n) is considered as lvalue.

Comment: `n` is an lvalue, and parentheses do not change the value category

Comment: @MM, by that logic, in statement decltype(n) a = 20, n should be considered as lvalue. But here a is an int. not int &.

Comment: It's actually `decltype(n)` that's special - the standard has a special case that discards "lvalue-ness" when the argument is an unparanthesized id-expression.

Comment: There's no `(n)` expression in `decltype(n)` .  The syntax is `decltype(` *expression or id* `)`, not `decltype` *expression*

Comment: @M.M : Got it. Can you please post this as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `n` is an lvalue  ; and putting parentheses around an expression does not change the value category.

As covered in [the question already linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used):

- `decltype( (n) )` is the syntax `decltype(` *`expression`* `)`
- `decltype( n )` is the syntax `decltype(` *`id`* `)`  .

The latter is not `decltype` *`expression`* with an expression of `(n)`, there is no such syntax.

Answer (score 4):

`(n)` is an lvalue of type `int`, and so `decltype((n))` is `int&`. Now, `n` is also an lvalue of type `int` - but there's a special case in the definition of `decltype` for when its argument is an unparenthesized *id-expression*, that makes `decltype(n)` come out as `int`.

> **[dcl.type.simple]/4** For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
> ...
> (4.2) — otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access (8.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`...;
> ...
> (4.4) — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`...

Answer (score 1):

It might be insightful to compare the expression `(n)` with `n+0` or `n*1` or `n|0`. All are expressions, and all these expressions have the same value as `n`. All these expressions are lvalues.