# How to compare data type of a tuple parameter?

Tags: c++, windows

How i could compare the data type of each tuple argument?

```
enum WinGetCmds {
    WINGET_TITLE, WINGET_CLASS
};


template <typename... Args>
auto WinGet(WinGetCmds cmd, Args&&... args)
{
    auto pack = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    switch (cmd)
    {
    case WINGET_TITLE:
    {
        auto arg_1 = std::get<0>(pack);

        if constexpr (std::is_same<arg_1, std::wstring>::value)
        {
          //...
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<arg_1, HWND>::value)
        {
          //...
        }    

    }
    break;

    }
}


WinGet(WINGET_TITLE, L"ABC");
```

In the template above I'm getting an error in the `constexpr` line:

```
'std::is_same': 'arg_1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty1'7
```

What other way I could compare the data type of `arg_1`?

Comment: `arg_1` is an expression not a type. You could use `decltype(arg_1)`

Comment: @JasonLiam and how to dynamic `decltype` according to the arg1 data type?

Comment: See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W9s6Ev41e) that uses `decltype(arg_1)` same as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577422/12002570) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What other way I could compare the data type of arg_1?

The problem is that `arg_1` is an expression when you use it in an expression. That is, you cannot use it as a template type parameter for `is_same` which is what the error is trying to say.

To solve this, you could use, `decltype(arg_1)`.

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W9s6Ev41e)

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading the docs of `decltype` but I'm still confused about what it really does, what's the difference from `decltype(arg_1)` and `typeid(arg_1)`? they do the same but `typeid` only 'works' with constants?

Comment: @Mike `decltype` and `typeid` have different purposes and different rules. For more examples and explanation on `decltype` refer to [What is decltype and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used). You're welcome.